# CreateOrUpdate Operation Over Many Records Using Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing a web crawler for fun.

I have a remote SQL database that I want to save information about each page I visit and I am using Entity Framework 6 to persist data. For the sake of illustration, let's assume that the only data I want to save about each page is the last time I visited it.

Updating this database is very slow. Here is the operation that I want make fast:

1. For the current page, check if it exists in the database already
2. If it exists already, update the "lastVisited" timestamp field on the record and save.
3. If it doesn't exist, create it.

Currently I can only do 300 updates per minute. My SQL server instance shows almost no activity, so I assume I am client-bound.

My code is naive:

```
public static void AddOrUpdatePage(long id, DataContext db)
    {
        Page p = db.Pages.SingleOrDefault(f => f.id == id);

        if (p == null)
        {   
            // create
            p = new Page();
            p.id = id;
            db.Pages.Add(p);
        }

        p.lastSeen = DateTime.Now;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I crawl a bunch of pages (1000s), and then call AddOrUpdatePage in a loop for each page.

It seems like the way to get more speed is batching? What is the best way to get 1000 records from my database at a time, given a set of page ids? In SQL I would use a table variable for this and join, or use a lengthy IN clause.

Comment: I have read that even if I batch my reads, my writes will be unbatched even if I wait to save them every 1000 records? Is there any way to force EF to send my creates as one large SQL command instead of a million small ones?

Comment: Are you reusing your DbContext db? If you are reusing it then you could use the method Find instead of SingleOrDefault. It will check first if the entity with that key is already cached in the context. Otherwise, for top performance I would recommend using plain Ado.Net against a stored procedure.